# Fill in cells with alternating pattern

Tags: r

I am trying to fill in blank cells with the value of rows above. Similar to na.locf function, but I have a pattern that needs to be matched. I don't necessarily know how many rows between new values (i.e betweem a,b and c,d).

I have used the na.locf and searched around for a solution to no avail.

```
df <- df <- data.frame(col1 = c("a","b", NA, NA, NA, NA, "c", "d", NA, NA))
df
#    col1
# 1     a
# 2     b
# 3  <NA>
# 4  <NA>
# 5  <NA>
# 6  <NA>
# 7     c
# 8     d
# 9  <NA>
# 10 <NA>
```

Solution I would like:

```
df
col1
a
b
a
b
a
b
c
d
c
d
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Does your data have the literal `"NA"` in it, or are they the `NA` special values? (I rarely see a literal string `"NA"` in my research/work, but that might be just an artifact of (1) the sources of my data, and just as importantly (2) how I read it in and process it.

Comment: They are the NA special values.

Comment: Okay, great. When you make data, please keep it as realistic as possible, don't just type it in. If this is your data, then `dput(df)` (`dput(head(df,n=10))` if large) will give a good, accurate, representative object for us to play with. (You would just paste the output of that into the question, in a [code-block](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).)

Answer (score 2):

```
ave(df$col1,
    with(rle(!is.na(df$col1)), rep(cumsum(values), lengths)),
    FUN = function(x){
        rep(x[!is.na(x)], length.out = length(x))
    })
# [1] a b a b a b c d c d
```

Comment: Maybe `rep(x[!is.na(x)], ...)` to make it generalized? +1

Answer (score 1):

Here's way with `dplyr`. You can drop the `group` column if needed. -

```
df %>% 
  group_by(group = cumsum(is.na(lag(col1)) & !is.na(col1))) %>%
  mutate(
    col1 = rep(col1[!is.na(col1)], length.out = n())
  ) %>% 
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 10 x 2
   col1  group
   <chr> <int>
 1 a         1
 2 b         1
 3 a         1
 4 b         1
 5 a         1
 6 b         1
 7 c         2
 8 d         2
 9 c         2
10 d         2
```